# Validate if its a string or not

Tags: python, string, validation

I am not getting it right and I can't find how to do it.

Get the user input and create a thematic list of strings. The program should ask for a specific input theme.
The user should enter strings for the list until a condition is met such as entering a specific word or character.
There should not be hard coded list size.?
Each user input should be one list element.

```py
MyList = []

for _ in range(5):
    planets = str(input("Enter 5 planets: "))
    if planets == str(planets):
        if planets not in MyList:
            MyList.append(planets)
    else:
        print("Input not valid")

print("That's your planets: ")
print(str(MyList))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand. To validate if something is a string should be `isinstance(something, str)`. But [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returns a string. There is no need to do extra validation.
By the way, if you only want to eliminate duplicated items, I suggest using a set instead of a list. Call str() for print() is also redundant because print() will do the conversion itself. So:

```py
print("Enter 5 planets: ")
result = {input(f"{i}) ") for i in range(1, 6)}
print("That's your planets:", ", ".join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyList = []

for _ in range(5):
    planets = input("Enter 5 planets: ")
    if type(planets) == str: 
        if planets not in MyList: 
            MyList.append(planets) 
        else: 
            print("Input not valid")

print("That's your planets: ")
print(",".join(MyList))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually any variable defined with the `input()` function will always be a `str` data type, because even if it's a number, it would still be the **string representation** of that number. Even if the user did not input any values ​​at all, it would still be an empty string `""`.

I'm not sure what kind of verification you are trying to do exactly on that input but if you want to verify that it's not a number you can use the`isdigit()` string method.

Here is a simple example:

```
planets = []

while True:

    planet = input("Insert the name of a planet: ")
    
    if planet == 'quit':
        break

    if not planet.isdigit() and not planet in planets:
        planets.append(planet)

print("Here is your list of planets:")
for planet in planets:
print(planet)
```

This block of code continually prompts the user to enter a `planet` name until the keyword *quit* is entered. If the input is not a number and is not already in the `planets` list, it is added. Finally, the complete list of planets is shown.

It must be said that on a conceptual level this implementation does not make much sense. It would be more logical to have a list of all known planets and check if the entered input matches any of the entries in the list. In that case, checking if the string represents a number becomes rather pointless.